# What is the purpose of TabPage.Hide()

Tags: c#, winforms, show-hide, tabpage

When the TabPage.Hide() doesn't have any effect why is still available? 
**tcImgBase.TabPages["tabPage3"].Hide();**

The general implementation to hide a tab page is to remove it. 
Can someone explain the scope of Hide & Show?

Comment: To add to siride's answer: The Visibility property is not exposed in the Designer nor in Intellisense. Which should be read here (!) as a hint. (There are other cases where such an omission hints at nothing, e.g. MouseWheel..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Hide()` method just changes the `Visible` property. It's implemented in the `Control` class, which is the base class for all Windows Forms controls. That means that all controls have this method and property and it can't be hidden since that's how C# works. However, it's not meaningful for all controls, such as `TagPage` and, indeed, the MSDN documentation says as much:

> This member is not meaningful for this control.

And later:

> To hide a tab in a TabControl, you must remove it from the control's TabPages collection.

Both from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y6e1ah1k(v=vs.100).aspx.